# Can not apply changes in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I put my website on server IIS. The physical path for that site like '

> c:\Apps\webUI

'.And

> V4.0

is application pool for this site.first i check the site work perfect.Then I replace some page for apply changes and then restart,refresh website and application pool but its not reflect. When I see my site in browser its not seen changes.

I also try to remove some changes but not any reflect on the site.

Can give me proper solution for this?

Comment: try recycling your app pool

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the browser cache?  `ctrl+F5` usually does the trick.

Comment: yes. I also try ctrl+f5 and recycling applicaion pool. It's not work

Comment: What are the changes c# code js or css ?

Comment: Try iisreset from command line

Comment: In BAL Dll and aspx page.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reset iis by command line?

Comment: what changes did you make? was it javascript, html, server side code? Are you absolutely certain you are modifying files in the right directory?

Comment: I told in above comment :) .In HTML and server side

Comment: are you 100% certain you are making changes in  the right directory? When you open IIS Manager, is the directory the site pointing at the directory you are making changes?

Comment: refresh your website in iis server manager and browse the site from there,
also check permissions of newly added files

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no restart of the website, the application pool or the server (iisreset) is necessary to serve the latest content to the client.

How can you debug a situation like this?

Start with pressing F12 in your browser and open the network tab to inspect the requests. Do you get an http status of 200 or 304?

Force a reload using `Ctrl+F5` in the browser, do you get 200s now?

You can also try to clear the browser cache.

Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to inspect the web traffic outside of the browser.

On the server check your http logs to verify that new requests are coming in.

Still on the server verify, the requests are getting to the correct files. You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) for this.

Check the `Output Caching` settings in IIS